# overflow: hidden not working with more that 3 divs

Tags: html, css

I am struggling with my latest project with CSS overflow hidden and divs. Basically what I have right now is a structure like this:

```
<div class = "parent">
    <div class = "son">
        <p class = "text">1</p>
    </div>

    <div class = "son">
        <p class = "text">2</p>
    </div>

    <div class = "son">
        <p class = "text">3</p>
    </div>
    ...
</div>
```

Since I may change the amount of "son" divs, on parent div I used display flex, flex-direction column and also in the son divs I used the propriety flex: 1 in order to have responsive height.

So far everything works perfectly because son divs sets their height based on parent and are equally distributed.

The next step I took was adding inside each div a number which should not effect the height of the div but instead should appear in the div and if it goes off because is too large the overflowing part shouldn't be seen. I achieve this by creating the paragraph text and setting overflow hidden on the son class. You can see the effect on the image.

[image]

So far so good. The problem is that if I add more than 3 son divs with the paragraph inside. All the divs resize and mess up.

[image]

I would like that the divs remain exactly the same as the first image. Someone knows what could be? I think it may be the flex propriety on the son div but I actually need it to work so I am stuck and with no more ideas.
Thanks to everyone for the answers in advance.

Comment: Your second snippet has also that header _test_, your first is missing it. Please post full code for the second snippet

Comment: Can you show us your CSS?

Comment: Sorry for being late actually I putted my code snippet on jfiddle. You can check it out on the following link: jsfiddle.net/samueldeguio/3xr12Lsh. When you start the code you see how it should be, but if you try to decomment one of the paragraphs that are commented all boxes become bigger. I would like that they stay the same and keep the starting effect

Comment: All code relevant to your problem, belongs directly into your question - in text form & properly formatted; or as a Stack Snippet, in cases where that makes sense. _Do not_ just provide the reproducible example on an external platform only. Please edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edited answer (as per comment) - seems that you only need to add `height: 10rem;` to `.ch-number` - This make sense since you want to play with overflow of the div.

Exapmle:

```css
/* ------ GOOGLE FREE FONTS ------*/
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:100,200,700&display=swap'); /* Raleway -> font-family: 'Raleway';*/
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Titillium+Web:wght@900&display=swap'); /*Titillium font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;*/

.p1-slot{
  background-color: white;
  padding: 0;
  transition: .4s;
  padding-top: 1em;
  padding-left: 1em;
}

.p2-slot{
  clip-path: polygon(30% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
  padding: 0;
  transition: .4s;
  background-color: rgb(8, 6, 39);
  width: 20%;
}

.p2-slot.active{
  clip-path: polygon(20% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);

  transition: .4s;
}

.site-wrapper{ /*ridefinisco il colore del wrapper solo per questa pagina*/
  background-color: white;
}

.display-4{
   font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
   font-size: 2.5em;
   color: rgb(8, 6, 39);
}

.p2-slot .display-4{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: .3em;
  color: white;
  z-index: 1;
}

.choosen{
  height: 100%;
  width: 15em;

  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding-bottom: 1.5em;
}
.p2-slot .choosen{
  width: 16em;
}
.p2-slot .choosen{
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 0;
}

.choose_box{
  flex: 1;
  background-color: rgba(217, 217, 217, .4);
  border-bottom: .5em solid white;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  transition: .4s;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.choose_box.blocked{
  background-color: rgb(8, 6, 39);
  background-position: right;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
}

.ch-number{
  font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
  font-size: 12em;
  position: relative;
  color: rgba(217, 217, 217, .4);
  margin-top: -.5em;
  text-align: left;
height: 10rem; /* added*/
}

.choose_box.blocked .ch-number{
  color: var(--secondary_back);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <div class="container-fluid site-wrapper row">
    <div class="col-8 p1-slot">
      <div class="choosen">
        <p class = "display-4">some</p>
        <div class="p-2 choose_box">
          <p class="ch-number">1</p>
        </div>
        <div class="p-2 choose_box">
          <p class="ch-number">2</p>
        </div>
        <div class="p-2 choose_box">
          <p class="ch-number">3</p>
        </div>
        <div class="p-2 choose_box">
          <p class="ch-number">4</p>
        </div>
        <div class="p-2 choose_box">
          <p class="ch-number">5</p>
        </div>
        <div class="p-2 choose_box">
          <p class="ch-number">6</p>
        </div>
        <div class="p-2 choose_box">
          <p class="ch-number">7</p>
        </div>
        <div class="p-2 choose_box">
          <p class="ch-number">8</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4 p2-slot text-right">
      <div class="choosen">
        <p class = "display-4">other</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

---

Old answer:

Since you didn't provide `css` code, you can modify this general example as you wish. I put some additional notes inside.

```css
.son {
  position: relative; /* since child .text use absolute position */
  overflow: hidden; /* since we want to "cut" .text string */
  background: silver; 
  height: 100px; width: 100px; 
  margin: 10px 0;
}
.text {
  position: absolute; bottom: -25px; left: 0; 
  margin: 0; /* .text is <p> so we need to clear that initial margins */
  font: bold 80px arial,sans-serif; 
  color: gray; 
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="son">
    <p class="text">1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="son">
    <p class="text">2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="son">
    <p class="text">3</p>
  </div>
  <div class="son">
    <p class="text">4</p>
  </div>
  <div class="son">
    <p class="text">5</p>
  </div>
  <div class="son">
    <p class="text">6</p>
  </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry for being late actually I putted my code snippet on jfiddle. You can check it out on the following link: https://jsfiddle.net/samueldeguio/3xr12Lsh/. When you start the code you see how it should be, but if you try to decomment one of the paragraphs that are commented all boxes become bigger. I would like that they stay the same and keep the starting effect.

Comment: Tthank you. You are amazing, the solution worked perfectly.